# Cassandra NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/common/util/concurrent/AsyncFunction

Tags: cassandra, datastax-java-driver

```
cluster = Cluster.builder()                                                    
                .addContactPoint("localhost")
                .build();

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/common/util/concurrent/AsyncFunction
```

The only jars I have in my path are the 2 cassandra java driver jars cassandra-driver-core-2.1.10.3.jar and cassandra-driver-mapping-2.1.10.3.jar

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

The issue is with missing guava.jar. Adding this in the class path solved (this) issue.
**Overall issue is lack of suitable DataSatx documentaion**